How to time-efficiently supervise students to learn a new topic while working on a project?
I'm currently a post-doc and I'm supervising several projects at once - some of them distantly, basically only via videocalls.
In one of the projects, which I found very promising initially, there are 5 students, 4 of them at the university abroad, so I can meet with them only rarely in person. While all of them have mathematical background I found out, that it's not what I expected as it seems, that the quality of courses dropped significantly in this university due to internal conflicts and abrupt management changes. Moreover, it seems, that they have basically no knowledge of quantum mechanics, which is required for the project and which they were taught in some introductory course. When I asked them, it seemed, that most of the courses were done in a "read it yourself" way with some easy-to-pass exam.
Knowing this and not having time to basically teach a QM course distantly, I decided to send them my favorite textbook and told them to go through it chapter-by-chapter, as it contains many easy exercises making it easy to comprehend the basic QM concepts. Additionally, I offered "a group consultation" in a way, that students would send me their questions beforehand and I prepared a slideshow and some PDF with equations trying to explain the topic in as much mathematically rigorous way as possible in our time frame, providing also a list of topics, sources and general directions you should go through if you want to understand the topic in-depth.
But, it converged into another 2 problems:

Students are not nearly as involved as I expected them to be, despite most of them having at least a part-time job on the research project as they like to code and run some simulations and quite obviously consider the rigorous background to be somewhat superfluous (even when I tried to explain very clearly, that it's important if they're aspiring to become more independent researchers and also fully-functional in the scope of the project).

I originally meant (and stated it clearly), that they should ask questions about the chapter so that we'll consult it coherently with their study progress. While it's the case sometimes, many times (with increasing tendency) the questions are very broad and obviously motivated by some popularization videos rather than specific to the current chapter. While I'm also explaining these, it's usually taking a lot of my time as the question typically isn't trivial and, most notably, it requires some additional mathematical knowledge (i.e. representation theory) they don't have and will obtain after several months, if studying as planned.


Shortly, I'm not sure how to proceed here as the students are obviously willing to work on the project, but their lack of knowledge in some subjects (albeit they should possess it) is hindering progress and the consultations aren't really as useful as they could be. Do you have any similar experience?

Are all your groups working on the same project? That is, are they independent and replicating the work/tasks of other groups? Or are they each doing different things?

@Buffy Two of them are working on a project mostly supervised by my colleague where I'm only overseeing the software implementation. The remaining three are working on the same project fully under mine supervision.

I have had luck with using a  mailing list (old tech, I know) to which every student was enrolled as well as contributing faculty. This might work for your "three" group. And maybe separately for the other two.
The advantage of email over other social media is that they don't need to be connected at the same time.
The rules were that anyone could ask questions on the list at any time of the day or night and anyone could answer. I had to monitor the conversations so that I could correct wrong answers and sometimes provide answers and guidance myself.
I could also point them to resources that they needed to examine at the moment and prompt them with questions and such.
My experience was that most questions got answered within a few hours and, after a while, I only had to jump in occasionally.
If you use this with the "two" group, I'd suggest that the other faculty member take the lead and you just add what you can when necessary. This might reduce the burden on yourself, or not, depending on how much the software is a block for them.
While my course only met in person once a month (for several hours) it was a 24/7 operation throughout from the student standpoint and not especially burdensome on my part. But you have to encourage them to answer as well as ask. They can also carry on a group meeting or "strategy session" online this way but non-synchronistically. That can be helpful for people in different time zones.
